# In-place updating of Azure VM Operating System

Tags: azure

Is there a way to in-place update the OS of an Azure VM, i.e. from Windows Server 2012 R2 to Windows Server 2016 within the Azure Portal?

My Azure VM is currently deployed under the resource model.

Comment: For now, Azure does not support this. Also, based on my experience, it maybe cause some compatibility issues. If possible, you had better migrate your app to new VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **Microsoft does not support an upgrade of the operating system of a Microsoft Azure virtual machine**.

Instead, you should create a new Azure virtual machine that is running the supported version of the operating system that is required and then migrate the workload. Instructions for how to migrate Windows Server roles and features are available in the following TechNet topic:

[Install, use, and remove Windows Server migration tools](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj134202)

More information please refer to this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2721672/microsoft-server-software-support-for-microsoft-azure-virtual-machines).